# How to save an arbitrarily large image to a file in XNA?

Tags: xna, textures, maps

I have built a level editor for an XNA-based Megaman clone I am working on and one of the features I would like to implement is the ability to save a full-resolution map of the entire level (like [this one](http://www.nesmaps.com/maps/MegaMan2/MegaMan2AirManMap.html)). My problem is that the levels can be arbitrarily large and XNA has a texture size limit of 4028x4028. I don't need to use the texture for anything in the editor itself, only to save it to disk.

I have stored the image data in an array using game.GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData, but I am having trouble finding a way to store this to disk in a readable format (preferably PNG). Everything I've found online says to use the Texture2D.SetData and Texture2D.SaveAsPng methods, but those calls are restricted to the 4028x4028 max texture size.

Any suggestions?

Note: I do realize that the example map I linked above was likely created by hand and while I could certainly output multiple full-resolution images of each screen and put them together by hand in Photoshop, I would like the process to be available directly in the editor if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way around `Texture2D` size limit, so my suggestion is the following:

1. Add a reference to `System.Drawing` to your project.
2. Create an instance of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to store your map. I don't think there's a size limit using `Bitmap`, because I even tried with sizes over 15000 pixels wide and it worked.
3. Write your data to the `Bitmap`. The easy but slow way is to use `Bitmap.SetPixel`. The harder but significantly faster way is to use `Bitmap.LockBits` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx)). You'll also need to convert your colors from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` to `System.Drawing.Color` but that is easy with `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb`.
4. Save `Bitmap` as a PNG to file by calling `Save` with `ImageFormat.Png` as the second parameter.

Example using the slow method:

```cs
bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
for (int x = 0; x != width; ++x)
    for (int y = 0; y != height; ++y)
       bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
bitmap.Save("level.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

But I warn you that it will perform extremely slow, so use it only as a test drive, and then switch over to the `LockBits` method.